# Coroutine in Vertx never execute?

Tags: kotlin, vert.x, kotlin-coroutines

In Vert.x, suppose I have functions like this:

```
fun caller() {
    runBlocking {
        val job = GlobalScope.launch(vertx.dispatcher()) {
            val r = suspendPart()
            println(r) // never execute
        }
        println(1) // printed
        job.join()
        println(2) // never execute
    }
}

suspend fun asyncPart(): Future<Int> {
    val promise: Promise<Int> = Promise.promise()
    delay(500)
    promise.complete(0)
    return promise.future()
}

suspend fun suspendPart(): Int {
    return asyncPart().await()
}
```

r(which is 0) and 2 will never be printed, only 1 is printed. How should I fix it?
My intention is to wait for `asyncPart` completes (I have a `AsyncResult` inside actually).

Answer (score 1):

Presumably your `caller()` method is called by vert.x and this means you're breaking one of the pivotal rules of vert.x:

## Don’t block me!

Vert.x is mostly based on very fast single-threaded work, what this means is that when you block the thread in `caller`, it is unable to execute the coroutine scheduled with `launch` leading to a deadlock.

The proper way to solve this is to remove your blocking code through the integration vert.x provides for kotlin coroutines.

Alternatively using a different dispatcher for `launch` would also work since the other thread would unblock the vert.x dispatcher. But this would not solve the primary issue of blocking calls in the vert.x dispatcher.

Comment: Kiskae, these are part of my application initial codes, a little bit blocking is acceptable to me. In my situation, I need to wait for the `AsyncResult`, `await()` function perfectly works. However, using `await()` function needs me to make the function `suspend `, and to call the suspend function, I need to use coroutine with `runBlocking`. You mentioned that using a different dispatcher would work, could you please show an example? Thanks.

Comment: I found a simple solution by your suggestion, just create a new vertex and use it to create a dispatcher: `Vertx.vertx().dispatcher()`

Comment: I found a simple solution by your suggestion, just create a new vertex and use it to create a dispatcher: `Vertx.vertx().dispatcher()`